Conditional styling of Text component in React Native
Why does this conditional styling work for Presseble, but at the same time doesn't work for Text? How can I make it correct for the Text component too?
<Pressable style={ () => { return flagA == 0 ? styles.pressable_1 : styles.pressable_2 } } >
<Text style={ () => { return flagA == 0 ? styles.text_1 : styles.text_2 } }>{L5}</Text>


It's not working for , because the style prop for  does not accept a function in the same way  does. For , the style prop can be a function that receives the pressed state as a parameter. However, for , the style prop expects a direct style object or an array of styles.
To fix this for text, you can use a conditional expression to decide which style to apply.
Correct Code:
<Pressable style={() => (flagA == 0 ? styles.pressable_1 : styles.pressable_2)}>
  <Text style={flagA == 0 ? styles.text_1 : styles.text_2}>{L5}</Text>
</Pressable>

